# space invaders Unity problem with execution order?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make space invaders game from ground up in unity. I have stumbled upon a problem with coding invaders. I coded the logic for moving them together right and left. But I have a problem with making them move all together down, when one of them reaches the edge of the game screen. My invaders are a prefab. So all of them have exact same code and are just copies of each other.

Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class invaderScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    float timer = 0;
    [SerializeField] float delay = 1;
    static bool movingRight = true;
    static bool movingLeft = false;
    static bool movingDown = false;
    [SerializeField] int speed = 1;
    float heightTimeDelay = 0;
    bool initialDelayPassed = false; // Added flag for initial delay

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        heightTimeDelay -= Time.deltaTime;

        // Check if initial delay has passed
        if (!initialDelayPassed)
        {
            if (timer >= delay)
            {
                initialDelayPassed = true;
                timer = 0; // Reset timer after initial delay
            }
            else
            {
                return; // Skip the rest of Update() until initial delay has passed
            }
        }

        movingDown = false;
        changeDirection();
        changeHeight();
        movingFunction();

    }

    void movingFunction()
    {
        if (timer > delay)
        {
            if (movingRight)
            {
                transform.Translate(Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
                timer = 0;
            }
            else if (movingLeft)
            {
                transform.Translate(Vector2.left * speed * Time.deltaTime);
                timer = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    void changeDirection()
    {
        if (transform.position.x > 7.5 && movingRight)
        {
            movingLeft = true;
            movingRight = false;
            movingDown = true;
        }
        else if (transform.position.x < -7.5 && movingLeft)
        {
            movingLeft = false;
            movingRight = true;
            movingDown = true;
        }
    }
    
    void changeHeight()
    {
        if (movingDown)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector2.down);
        }
    }
    
}
```

As you can see I am using static variables movingLeft, movingRight and movingDown. So that if one of the invaders touches the edge, all of their variables will change and they will all know that an action needs to be done. It works fine with movingRight and movingLeft. But with movingDown sometimes half of the invaders will move, sometimes one, it feels weird and random.

Here is a screenshot of my unity workspace: [image]

I hope someone knows whats up and how to fix this.

I presume that the problem is with the fact that some of them for some reasson don't get their static `movingDown` variable updated? So they don't move. Or, it updates too soon to false and they don't have time to move. I tried combatting this by putting `movingDown = false` to LateUpdate function or as you see in the code above in the beginning of the `Update` function, so that all invaders could move down, before the variable switches to false. Nonetheless, it doesn't work.

Comment: I have not coded unity, But you might consider creating a single script that updates all the the enemies. That might make the edge-check easier.

Comment: That is true, but its just weird that it works with x movement but for some reason doesn't with y...

Comment: well - one of your instances might be setting `moveDown = true` .. but already the next instance that is not on the edge will revert it to `moveDown = false` in the same frame ... the same thing does not happen with `moveLeft`/`moveRight` because there is only a very specific condition when you change those which can not be fulfilled by two instances in two contradicting cases => I'd agree with @JonasH: You want one single controller be responsible for moving and do all the checks so it has only one global state and moves all enemies in one frame in the same direction

Comment: How I thought it works is that before going to the next frame it should finish all of the update functions for all of the instances of the objects in the scene. But with what you are saying, update functions might be stretched to multiple frames which seems wrong?  Maybe that is how it works. In that case going to recode everything on one controller... @DerHugo

Also as I have said I tried putting moveDown=false to LateUpdate() which supposed to run after all of the Update() functions have been finished. It should have 100% finished the issue, of one instance reverting moveDown too early.

Comment: That's absolutely not what I'm saying, no, of course not. All `Update` are executed one after another in the same frame => In the first instance you might meat the condition and set `moveDown=true;` then it is the next instance's turn and in `Update` it sets `moveDown = false` ... within the very same frame

Comment: Your second part still doesn't mean that all instances are actually aware that `moveDown = true` for this frame ... only those that happen to get `Update` called **after** the instance that meats the condition for the edge ... in worst case this might mean none

Comment: If you added the distance between each enemy (increment) and what its "index" is, you could adjust the changeDirection function to be something like `if (transform.position.x > 7.5f - increment * index) ..`, that way each enemies edge distance is based on their relative distance to the edge (instead of the static 7.5).  It would be better to have a single controller as suggested above, but it is possible to keep them independent if needed.